# Daily vote limit reached yet votes on the vote cast page only add up to 32

Tags: discussion, bug, voting

Last two days I have been voting on some [recent community-wiki answers with 0 score](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0%20wiki%3ayes%20is%3aanswer), yesterday I used up my 40 votes (not to confused with [the user with this name](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85506/40-votes)).

However today, after the system gave me pop up that "Daily vote limit reached", I found that both on my profile page, and the votes casted page, the total votes only add up to 32.

Is this a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug. I'm sure that 40 votes will come shortly to explain the fine points of the 40 votes limit.

Comment: When the blue popup "you have $5$ votes left today" appears,  check your vote count. If it's $35$, carry on: you are on track to cast $40$ votes. If it's $n<35$, you can undo the last vote cast (which was on an answer) and cast $35-n$ votes on questions, lest they go to waste. Then resume what you were doing.